# User Level permission to different forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have code that works for opening one particular form, but I need to setup different user levels which can then be used to restrict access to different forms in the Access program.

I have a login screen which uses data (username/password) from a table `employee`, this table also has a foreign key column called `employeeTypeId`, additionally I have a table called `Access` which has different `employeetypeId` as `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`.

`5` is supposed to be admin and `1` is read-only user and so on. The third table is `EmployeeAccess` , it has `employeeTypeId` as well as column `HasAccess` with `yes/no` datatype.

I am using this to write a code in VBA to ensure only certain users have access to certain forms.

I have a code that works for one form, I am trying to figure out how to use this `HasAccess` column in conjunction with `employeeTypeId` and different form-names (need to figure out how to use that) to ensure `employeetypeId=5` users have access to all forms, `employeetypeId=4` has access to lets say all forms except `employee` table form and `employeetypeId=3` has access to edit only a select few forms and so on.

This is the code for accessing the form after login (on load):

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If DLookup("HasAccess", "EmployeeAccess", "EmployeeTypeId=" & TempVars("EmployeeType") & " AND FormName='" & Me.Name & "'" = False) Then
        MsgBox "Yo do not have access"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code in the login form:

```vb
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Employee", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

    rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.TextUserName & "'"
    If rs.NoMatch = True Then
        Me.LabelWrongUser.Visible = True
        Me.TextUserName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Me.LabelWrongUser.Visible = False

    If rs!Password <> Encrypt(Me.TextPassword) Then
        Me.LabelWrongPass.Visible = True
        Me.TextPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Me.LabelWrongPass.Visible = False
    TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeTypeId.Value
End Sub
```

Currently the code opens all the forms when login is correct, I want to change that and give access based on `employeeTypeId`.

[image: tblEmployeeAccess]

==========================

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
  Dim rs As Recordset
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Employee", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
  rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.TextUserName & "'"
  If rs.NoMatch = True Then
      Me.LabelWrongUser.Visible = True
      Me.TextUserName.SetFocus
      Exit Sub
  End If
  Me.LabelWrongUser.Visible = False
  If rs!Password <> Encrypt(Me.TextPassword) Then
      Me.LabelWrongPass.Visible = True
      Me.TextPassword.SetFocus
      Exit Sub
  End If
  Me.LabelWrongPass.Visible = False  
  TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeTypeId.Value  
  If DLookup("HasAccess", "EmployeeAccess", "EmployeeTypeId=" & TempVars("EmployeeType")) Then
      TempVars("FormName") = rs!FormName.Value And DoCmd.OpenForm (
```

I just want to know how to use the DoCmd.OpenForm with the TempVars("FormName") and if it is possible.

Comment: Use code behind menu/switchboard form to set visibility of buttons that open other forms. Use code to open forms as editable or non-editable. You provided a lot of info and code, none of which shows an attempt at controlling user access to forms and so there is no stated error to resolve. Make attempt and when you encounter specific issue post question.

Comment: Not sure why you have TempVars for form name. Maybe `DoCmd.OpenForm rs!FormName`

Comment: I figured out the logic, I just need to figure out how to use yes/no column input with dlookup...    If DLookup("FormName", "EmployeeAccess", "EmployeeTypeId=" & TempVars("EmployeeType") & " And HasAccess= " & True &" ) Then , how do I use HasAccess? it is giving me syntax error.

Comment: I am trying to use dlookup to find formName where employeeTypeId matches the tempvars("EmployeeType") and HasAccess is True, I am doing something wrong..cant figure out why I am getting a syntax error..

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code I was able to achieve the result:

**The Goal was to filter based on EmployeeTypeId and HasAccess set as True (A combination of both to open forms)**

`TempVars("FormName") = DLookup("FormName", "EmployeeAccess", "EmployeeTypeId=" &` `TempVars("EmployeeType") & " And HasAccess = " & True & " ")`

```
DoCmd.OpenForm TempVars("FormName")
```